# Magento2: How to generate shipping label using Fedex/DHL/UPS in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shipping-address, print, shipping-label

I am using Fedex/DHL/UPS in my magento2 store and now I want to print shipping label in my custom module by provide shipping address.

Is there any API available to handle this? or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well you have the https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.6-admin/tag/shipment#operation/salesShipmentRepositoryV1SavePost `POST /V1/shipment/` endpoint where you can save the data about shipping labels.

also, https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.6-admin/tag/shipmentidlabel#operation/salesShipmentManagementV1GetLabelGet `GET /rest/default/V1/shipment/{id}/label` is useful when you want to retrieve the shipping label data.